Ellie rig widgets are greyed out
I want to play around with the Ellie pose library from:
https://www.blender.org/download/demo-files/
Right now I see the following after enabling "Show Overlays":

I would like to turn on the widgets to control the face or hands for example but I'm lost. One of the problems I face is that everything is greyed out and I have no clue how this is done:


Go into the filter of the Outliner, activate the Disable in Viewports option and enable it for this collection:

